# What's the Jacobian of a bijective map on the domain boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, conformal-geometry, parametrization

To guarantee the bijectivity of a map, a necessary condition is the positivity of the Jacobian of the map. In general, we have the following lemma:

A continuously differential map $\mathbf G$ is locally bijective provided its Jacobian, denoted as $\det(J_{\mathbf G})$, does not vanish on the parametric domain, and the global bijectivity of $\mathbf G$ is guaranteed if it is locally bijective on the parametric domain, and the computational domain is simply connected and the restriction of $\mathbf G$ on the domain boundary is bijective.

In our situation, we assume that the computational domain $\Omega$ is simply connected, and a bijective boundary correspondence of the parametric domain $\hat{\Omega}$ and computational domain $\Omega$ is established. Thus in this case, a locally bijective parameterization is also globally bijective.

My questions is: If the Jacobian $\det(J_{\mathbf G})$ is positive everywhere interior the parametric domain $\hat{\Omega}$, is the map $\mathbf G$ bijective? In other words, what is the Jacobian of a bijective map on the domain boundary, positive or zero?

Comment: I guess I do not understand your questions. For the first one, certainly $f$ is injective on an open convex set if its Jacobian matrix is positive definite there. But why would $f$ even be defined on the boundary? And what does it mean for $f$ to be differentiable there? You would need to extend it to an open nbhd.

Comment: Why can not $f$ be defined on the boundary?

Comment: But $f$ may $not$ be defined on the boundary, and even if it is defined on the boundary, differentiability requires that the domain be extendable to an open set which would then include points outside the original domain. Or may be I just do not understand your question.

Comment: On the boundary, we can define the semi-differentiability (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability), thus the Jacobian in my case denotes the semi-jacobian.

Comment: No. Semi-differentiability is not always possible. $f(x)=1/x$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ but there is no way to extend the property to $[0,1].$

Comment: Actually I am not sure if the Jocobian on the boundary makes sense. From your answer, it seems that the Jacobian can only be defined interior a closed domain.